# iOS, alert with no button to dismiss?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to present an alert window with no button on it, that means user can't close it by themselves, only the code from mine can dismiss the alert. How to implement that?

Comment: You really shouldn't do this though!

Comment: @hypercrypt Please let us know why can't we do this. I have also used this type of alert in one of my app. I am dismissing the alert after some time.

Comment: I would agree, this seems like poor design from a UX perspective.

Comment: I can do this, but you shouldn't. as Da_smokes says, it is not a good user experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                  message:@"This is sample message."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
message.tag = 123;
[message show];
[message release]
```

use this to make alert with no button

To dismiss the alertview use some logic similar to this

```
UIAlertView *alert = (UIAlertView)[[self.view viewWithTag:123]
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
```